# I'm looking for suggestions on how to store things of value in my db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, currency

I have a requirement (pending) that allows the user to buy "credits" and then to trade those credits for real goods or services.

This is the first time I have had to do this in an application and I am concerned it would paint a target on my database's back.  A hacker could (in theory) change the amount of credits a user has and then "spend" those credits, or convert them to cash.

I'm building the solution in ruby/rails, but I am not limited to this tech.  I can even use an outside provider if it's more practical.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do this?   Would you encrypt your DB?  Would that be enough?

Comment: I agree this is opinion based... please don't close it.  please remember why this site was created.  To let programmers share opinions on how best to do things.  To let us talk to one another, and to help the good ideas rise.  This site should not be about copy paste.  Please before you vote to close ask yourself why you joined the site.  Was it to get answers or to share.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of different things to consider. When it comes to matters of security, there is never a silver bullet (anyone who suggests that is likely selling snake oil); rather, security often involves many different steps to mitigate and manage risks and also redundant layers of protection so that one is still protected if some subset of those layers fail for whatever reason.

In terms of storing monetary transactions, there are often a number of legal regulations that need to be followed, so I suggest consulting those in addition to other security measures. In terms of encrypting the database, there are many different ways to apply encryption... one can encrypt the database as a whole or individual rows of the database using different keys. If you just encrypt the database as  a whole, it won't provide you much protection if someone has access to the key (which also begs the question of who has the key, where is it stored, etc.?). What you probably want, in addition to the database itself, is a write-only log of transactions with some sort of checksumming so that you can be assured of its authenticity that provides you with an audit trail that is independent of the database (and from which the database could be reconstructed in the event of some sort of breach). In addition, you'll want to ensure that only authorized applications (such as your production instance of your frontend server) can talk to and decrypt the database (and ensure that only a very limited number of people you trust can deploy new versions of those, so that no one can arbitrarily deploy malicious versions that abuse that access). If it's possible to independently encrypt individual rows with different keys (e.g. to encrypt each per-user row with key material derived from the user's login credential), then that is highly advisable (though this is not always possible to do, such as if you need to be able to process that row even when the user is not actively interacting with your application). I'm sure there are other things that I have not thought of, which is why you'll also want to regularly conduct penetration testing to check for any vulnerabilities (and not only fix anything you discover this way, but also use it to inform projects or processes that you can employ to prevent similar vulnerabilities in the future).

In addition to the security considerations, monetary transactions is one of the few cases where "eventual consistency" doesn't really work; you'll need to make sure that you are careful in your programming to make transactions appropriately atomic. That is, you wouldn't want the number of credits to decrease at a separate time step from the dispension of dollars, as that would allow the same credits to be spent twice... you'll want to be very careful in your coding that the decrease in credits and increase in dollars (or vice-versa) happen simultaneously. For this and other reasons thorough testing and good code review practice is a good idea.

Comment: thanks.. I was thinking of offloading it to a service that focuses on these things.  It's too bad paypal doesn't offer a credit storage system.

Comment: We might convert the cash value to loyalty points or the likes.  But the user can still cash them out.  So it still presents the same issues.  Any thoughts on out of the can solutions?  Any suggestions for implementing.. Not that I can't but I don't want to have to implement if I don't have to.

Comment: I think my comments still apply to the scenario you suggest.